# How to fetch all users by REST API in javascript

Tags: yammer

API doc is here https://developer.yammer.com/docs/usersjson

My javascript code below can successfully fetch the users in page 1 of yammer network.
But how to fetch all users by either one query or multiple queries in elegant way? I perceive that I need to query by looping against `page 1` `page 2` `page 3`... until the returned userArray length is 0? Then how do I validate when to stop in the loop?

```
yam.connect.loginButton('#yammer-login', function (resp) {
    console.log(resp.authResponse);
    if (resp.authResponse) {
        //trigger data process
        yam.platform.request({
            url: "users.json",     
            method: "GET",
            data: {    
                "page": 1
            },
            success: function (user) { 
                console.log("The request was successful.");
                console.dir(user);
            },
            error: function (user) {
                console.log("There was an error with the request.");
            }
        });
    }else{
        console.log("error to get access_token");
    }
});
```

Comment: if it's like any other decent API, there'll be a call that lets you ask how many entries there are for users.json, and how many results per query you're allowed, so that you can determine how many pages of results there will be. Or, that information might already be part of the platform.request response. Where's the API documentation?

Comment: Hi Mike, here it is. I don't see those information from the api doc here. https://developer.yammer.com/docs/usersjson

Comment: I don't see anything that says `page` is required, what happens if you just leave it off?

Comment: it pulls the data in page 1 only with 50 user objects in an array.